# asp.net - add data from textbox to database- After validation stopped working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Basically, I had the data which has been typed by users about their personal details into textboxs, after clicking submit button to go into the user table. This worked fine till I used validation on these textboxes and now all the validation works, however when submit is clicked it goes to the page I linked to the button however none of the data is being entered into the user table in the database now.

any ideas?

My code is shown below. Thank you

```
Protected Sub cmdSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSubmit.Click

   'add new user'
    Dim db As New LostPropertyDataContext
    Dim U As New tblUser With {.Forename = txtforename.Text, 
           .Surname = txtsurname.Text, .DateOfBirth = txtdob.Text, .Gender = txtgender.Text,
           .Address = txtaddress.Text, .Postcode = txtpostcode.Text, .TelephoneNo = txttelephoneno.Text,
           .MobileNo = txtmobileno.Text, .Email = txtemail.Text}
    db.tblUsers.InsertOnSubmit(U)
    db.SubmitChanges()
    Response.Redirect("/u1065977/LostPropertyProject/LostProperty2.aspx")


End Sub
```

Comment: have you check on debug whether these txtforename.Text have values.

Comment: it works fine during debug but not on my server. I don't understand :/

Comment: then try to debug it on the server. The first guess to problem that above code is not working is that you are not getting anything from client side hence have a blank row to add.

Comment: how do i debug on server?

Comment: is it a local IIS or a remote IIS

Comment: follow this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38132/Remote-IIS-Debugging-Debug-your-ASP-NET-Applicatio

Comment: @MaryamAhmed  Just so I understand: you are getting data on your development machine, even with the validators, but not on your server? How do you know you aren't getting data?  Are blank rows being inserted?  Errors on insert?

Answer (score 0):

When you say you added validation, I assume you mean that you added validation controls to your page.

It's a good practice -- one might say, a necessary practice -- to wrap your code in a test for whether validation passes:

```
If Page.IsValid Then
   'add new user'
   Dim db As New LostPropertyDataContext
   Dim U As New tblUser With {.Forename = txtforename.Text, 
       .Surname = txtsurname.Text, .DateOfBirth = txtdob.Text, .Gender = txtgender.Text,
       .Address = txtaddress.Text, .Postcode = txtpostcode.Text, .TelephoneNo = txttelephoneno.Text,
       .MobileNo = txtmobileno.Text, .Email = txtemail.Text}
   db.tblUsers.InsertOnSubmit(U)
   db.SubmitChanges()
   Response.Redirect("/u1065977/LostPropertyProject/LostProperty2.aspx")
End If
```

You're attempting to update without checking for whether validation has passed on the server side.  If you are using any custom validation (such as the `CustomValidator`) you're not giving it the chance to report back to you that something failed.

Comment: Yes. I am using validation controls and using the properties to come back with an error if a field is not filled in properly but how do I get it check the validation?

Comment: Just wrap your code in `If Page.IsValid Then ... End If`.  The property `Page.IsValid` will be false if server-side validation failed.

Comment: Still doesnt work- I have put the code behind the button. is this correct? because it still doesn't seem to be adding the data from the textboxes into the database

Comment: Can you post some of the HTML from your page, including the validators?  I wonder if something is set up incorrectly.

Comment: This is some of my code-  
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" 
        runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtemail" 
        ErrorMessage="Email format is wrong" 
        ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        <br />       
        <asp:Button ID="cmdSubmit" runat="server" Text="Next" BackColor="#339966" 
        BorderColor="White" ForeColor="White" Height="36px" Width="67px" />